# Why isn't my Stringer interface method getting invoked? When using fmt.Println

Tags: go

Suppose I have the following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Car struct{
    year int
    make string
}

func (c *Car)String() string{
    return fmt.Sprintf("{make:%s, year:%d}", c.make, c.year)
}

func main() {
    myCar := Car{year:1996, make:"Toyota"}
    fmt.Println(myCar)
}
```

When I call fmt.Println(myCar) and the object in question is a pointer, my String() method gets called properly.  If, however the object is a value, my output is formatted using the default formatting built into Go and my code to format the said object is not called.

The interesting thing is in either case if I call myCar.String() manually it works properly whether my object is either a pointer or value.

How can I get my object formatted the way I want no matter if the object is value-based or pointer-based when used with Println?

I don't want to use a value method for String because then that means every time it's invoked the object is copied which seams unreasonable.  And I don't want to have to always manually called .String() either because I'm trying to let the duck-typing system do it's work.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

When calling `fmt.Println`, `myCar` is implicitly converted to a value of type `interface{}` as you can see from the function signature. The code from the `fmt` package then does a [type switch](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) to figure out how to print this value, looking something like this:

```
switch v := v.(type) {
case string:
    os.Stdout.WriteString(v)
case fmt.Stringer:
    os.Stdout.WriteString(v.String())
// ...
}
```

However, the `fmt.Stringer` case fails because `Car` doesn't implement `String` (as it is defined on `*Car`). Calling `String` manually works because the compiler sees that `String` needs a `*Car` and thus automatically converts `myCar.String()` to `(&myCar).String()`. For anything regarding interfaces, you have to do it manually. So you either have to implement `String` on `Car` or always pass a pointer to `fmt.Println`:

```
fmt.Println(&myCar)
```

Comment: I suppose it is also partly because the language won't give you a pointer to what is stored inside an interface value (since that address may end up representing a different type if something else is assigned to the interface).

Comment: @JamesHenstridge, why not to leave old value in a pointer in that case?

Answer (score 28):

> Methods
>
> [Pointers vs. Values](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values)
>
> The rule about pointers vs. values for receivers is that value methods
>   can be invoked on pointers and values, but pointer methods can only be
>   invoked on pointers. This is because pointer methods can modify the
>   receiver; invoking them on a copy of the value would cause those
>   modifications to be discarded.

Therefore, for your `String` method to work when invoked on both pointers and values, use a value receiver. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Car struct {
    year int
    make string
}

func (c Car) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("{make:%s, year:%d}", c.make, c.year)
}

func main() {
    myCar := Car{year: 1996, make: "Toyota"}
    fmt.Println(myCar)
    fmt.Println(&myCar)
}
```

Output:

```
{make:Toyota, year:1996}
{make:Toyota, year:1996}
```

Comment: Does this basically mean that if i have a large struct, that every time it goes through Println It will be copied?  Like I said in my post this seams unreasonable.

Comment: @RalphCaraveo No, the argument type is `interface{}` which contains type information and a pointer to the struct.  The struct itself is not copied.

Comment: @SnoProblem Isn't it the case that the struct **is not** going to be copied when passed on to the `Println` function however **it is** going to be copied when passed on to the `func (c Car) String() string` function?

Answer (score 7):

Define your fmt.Stringer on a pointer receiver:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Car struct {
        year int
        make string
}

func (c *Car) String() string {
        return fmt.Sprintf("{maker:%s, produced:%d}", c.make, c.year)
}

func main() {
        myCar := Car{year: 1996, make: "Toyota"}
        myOtherCar := &Car{year: 2013, make: "Honda"}
        fmt.Println(&myCar)
        fmt.Println(myOtherCar)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/RGKK3mW6C_)

---

Output:

```
{maker:Toyota, produced:1996}
{maker:Honda, produced:2013}
```

Then, always pass a pointer to instances of Car to fmt.Println. This way a potentially expensive value copy is avoided under your control.

Answer (score 6):

The OP further asked:

> OP: **[when a value receiver is used]** *"Does this basically mean that if I have a large struct, then every time it goes through Println it will be copied?"*

The following experiment is evidence that the answer is "yes" (when a value receiver is used). Note that the `String()` method increments the year in this experiment, and check how this affects the printed output.

```
type Car struct {
    year int
    make string
}

func (c Car) String() string {
    s := fmt.Sprintf("{ptr:%p, make:%s, year:%d}", c, c.make, c.year)
    // increment the year to prove: is c a copy or a reference?
    c.year += 1
    return s
}

func main() {
    myCar := Car{year: 1996, make: "Toyota"}
    fmt.Println(&myCar)
    fmt.Println(&myCar)
    fmt.Println(myCar)
    fmt.Println(myCar)
}
```

With a value receiver `(c Car)`, the following printed output shows that Go makes value copies of the `Car` struct, because the year increment is not reflected in subsequent calls to `Println`:

```
{ptr:%!p(main.Car={1996 Toyota}), make:Toyota, year:1996}
{ptr:%!p(main.Car={1996 Toyota}), make:Toyota, year:1996}
{ptr:%!p(main.Car={1996 Toyota}), make:Toyota, year:1996}
{ptr:%!p(main.Car={1996 Toyota}), make:Toyota, year:1996}
```

Changing the receiver to a pointer `(c *Car)` but changing nothing else, the printed output becomes:

```
{ptr:0xc420094020, make:Toyota, year:1996}
{ptr:0xc420094020, make:Toyota, year:1997}
{1998 Toyota}
{1998 Toyota}
```

Even when a pointer is provided as argument in a call to `Println`, i.e. `fmt.Println(&myCar)`, Go still makes a value copy of the `Car` struct *when a value receiver is used.* The OP wants to avoid value copies being made, and my conclusion is that only pointer receivers satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It's only related to implementation of  `fmt` instead of Go however.

String() with pointer receiver would be invoked by https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew since `spew` print things in  this way:

```
v = reflect.ValueOf(arg)

...

switch iface := v.Interface().(type) {
    case fmt.Stringer:
        defer catchPanic(w, v)
        if cs.ContinueOnMethod {
            w.Write(openParenBytes)
            w.Write([]byte(iface.String()))
            w.Write(closeParenBytes)
            w.Write(spaceBytes)
            return false
        }
        w.Write([]byte(iface.String()))
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Generally speaking, it's best to avoid assigning values to variables via static initializers, i.e.

```
f := Foo{bar:1,baz:"2"}
```

This is because it can create exactly the complaint you're talking about, if you forget to pass `foo` as a pointer via `&foo` **or** you decide to use value receivers you end up making a lot of clones of your values.

Instead, try to assign pointers to static initializers *by default*, i.e.

```
f := &Foo{bar:1,baz:"2"}
```

This way `f` will always be a pointer and the only time you'll get a value copy is if you explicitly use value receivers.

*(There are of course times when you want to store the value from a static initializer, but those should be edge cases)*