# Unexplained behavior with pointers and protobufs

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I'm struggling to figure out a reason for this behavior, or maybe this is suppose to happen and I just wasn't aware.
For background, I'm using proto3, and am doing this in Go1.15, and I do know that packed is the default in proto3, and I'm relatively new to protobufs.

I defined the following message in a proto file:

```
message Response {
    repeated uint32 points = 1 [packed=true];
}
```

Which will generate the following code using protoc-gen-go v1.25.0.

```
type Response struct {
     state         protoimpl.MessageState
     sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
     unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

     Points []uint32 `protobuf:"varint,3,rep,packed,name=points,json=points,proto3" json:"points,omitempty"`
}
```

I go to use the new struct, and it doesn't behave like I would normally expect a struct to behave.  Here's some things I wrote, along with what was printed out.

```
newResponse := pb.Response{Points: []uint32{2,4,6,8}}
fmt.Println(newResponse)
//{{{} [] [] <nil>} 0 [] [2 4 6 8]  --> I expect this
refToNewResponse := &newResponse
fmt.Println(refToNewResponse)
// points:2  points:4  points:6  points:8 --> not what I expected
```

Now you might be thinking, it's just formatting big deal.
But I expect a list... not numbers that each individually have a label. I've seen and used other protobufs... and when I see the response that they return, it doesn't look like this, it's one label to a list like:

```
points: [2 4 6 8]
```

I do need to use the reference version of this because I eventually want to expand and use a list of Responses which the generated code will spit out a slice of pointer Responses, but I can't understand why it's separating and labeling each element in the slice.

I'm hoping someone can point out something I'm doing or not doing that is causing this... thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed **just formatting**. Nothing has changed in the underlying data structure. You requested a `repeated uint32 Points` and it's literally printing them that way.

The marshaler in the protobuf implementation can really output whatever it likes, **there is no reference version** of the human-readable representation of a protobuf.

If you really must have a custom format for the `.String()` output, you can try a different proto library such as [gogoprotobuf](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf), or try various extensions. But ultimately, it's just human-readable output.

Note:

- this has nothing to do with `packed=true` (which is indeed the default).
- if you're confused about printing the pointer vs the basic type, it's because the `String()` method has a pointer receiver. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976523/why-isnt-my-stringer-interface-method-getting-invoked-when-using-fmt-println)

Comment: Good answer. I'd also add the larger point that you shouldn't depend on anything that generates "debug output" like `String()`, or `__str__` in Python, or `DebugString()` in C++. If you do want human-readable, but somewhat dependable, output, use the actual text-proto libraries like `MarshalText()`.

Comment: Ah... alright. I appreciate such detailed answers. Good point about the MarshalText... I'll keep that in mind, thank you.